# how to click url inside image control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am converting pdf document to image using a itextsharp dll,in my requirement clickable url inside image control,how to click url inside image control.how to handle this...

thanks,
seelan

Answer (score 3):

You can have image inside of anchor tag, something like this :

```
<a title="href Title" href="url.html">
  <img src="image.jpeg" alt="image alt desc">
</a>
```